# Mutate or Make a new Array by replacing a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays (and the length can be in 1000s):

I want my array to replace status to the status of array 2. Here is the output example:

```
[{
value: 123,
status: 'demo',
type: '...'
},
{value: 2335,
 status: 'demo2',
 type: 'xxx'
}]
```

As we can see it needs to get the status from another array and replace it. What are the most possible efficient solutions for this? As this array can be very large. I don't know a good approach to solve this problem.
Length and sort order can be different, I need to replace array1's status by the array2's status,
By linking Array1's status and Array2's id

My actual Data

```
[
   {
    "id": "55",
    "status": "2",
    "type": "COD",
     "value": "5038.2",
   },
 {
   "id": "56",
   "status": "2",
   "type": "COD",
    "value": "5398.2",
  },
   {
    "id": "57",
    "status": "2",
    "type": "COD",
    "value": "10798.2",
  }

 ]
```

Array 2

```
[
   {
     "id": "1",
    "status": "Awaiting Confirmation",
   },
   {
    "id": "2",
    "status": "Confirmed",
   },
   {
    "id": "3",
     "status": "Awaiting Shipment",
  },
  {
     "id": "4",
    "status": "Awaiting Pickup",
   },
   {
    "id": "5",
    "status": "Shipped",
   },
 {
   "id": "6",
    "status": "Delivered",
   },
   {
     "id": "7",
    "status": "Cancelled",
  },
  {
   "id": "8",
    "status": "Refund Requested",
   },
   {
     "id": "9",
     "status": "Refunded",
   }
```

Things i have tried...I have used lodash and a for loop to achieve  this

```
const output = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        const statuscode = array1[i].status;
        const result = _.find(array2, { id: statuscode });
        output.push({
          value: array1[i].value,
          status: result.status,
          type: array1[i].type
        });
      }
      console.log(output);
```

Comment: so, what have you tried, even if it is not as performant, as it could be.

Comment: Okay..i will update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For high performance, transform one of the arrays to a `Map` first. Map lookups are very efficient:

```js
const input1 = [{
    value: 123,
    status: 1,
    type: 'COD',
  },
  {
    value: 2335,
    status: 2,
    type: 'COD',
  },
  {
    value: 222,
    status: 3,
    type: 'COD',
  }
];
const input2 = [{
    id: 1,
    status: 'demo'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    status: 'demo2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    status: 'demo3'
  }
];
const map2 = new Map(Object.values(input2).map(({ id, status }) => [id, status]));
const output = input1.map(({ status, ...rest }) => {
  const otherStatus = map2.get(status);
  return { ...rest, status: otherStatus };
});
console.log(output);
```

Code readability generally matters more than speed, but if you wanted, you could transform the `.map` transformation into a `for` loop as well:

```js
const input1 = [{
    value: 123,
    status: 1
  },
  {
    value: 2335,
    status: 2
  },
  {
    value: 222,
    status: 3
  }
];
const input2 = [{
    id: 1,
    status: 'demo'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    status: 'demo2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    status: 'demo3'
  }
];
const map1 = new Map(Object.values(input1).map(({ value, status }) => [status, value]));
const output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < input2.length; i++) {
  const { id, status } = input2[i];
  output.push({ value: map1.get(id), status });
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explination, But i am getting undefined for value, Here is my actual data, maybe you can look into it, Question updated

Comment: See edit. Please post questions with data structures that correspond to your actual data *before* people start answering them.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop would do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  array1[i].status = array2[i].status;
}
```

This of course assumes that the length and the order of the two arrays is the same.

**EDIT**

Alternative solution using `Array.prototype.find` and taking into account different lengths and orders.

```
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  const buffer = array1[i];
  buffer.status = array2.find(x => x.id === buffer.status).status;
}
```

Also, I would highly recommend giving priority to readability over [premature optimisation](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: Assumes lengths and sort order are the same. Not clear if they are in question

Comment: @charlietfl seems to be the case by what OP posted, but I'll clarify

Comment: It wont be in order and there is no 0 value .....and the status in array2 can be anything